# Ignore the 1st row(header) in a csv files using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, csv

Following is my csv file

**Contact Id,Customer Code,Billing Account Code,Bank BSB,Bank ID
2222222220,2222222222222220,100,084004,fjksanfjkdsksdnfnkjsnQ==
3333333330,3333333333333330,100,084789,sklsnfksnkdfnkgndfkjgn==**

and this is the code I'm using to ignore header & any row which has no data in any of 5 columns

```
while IFS=',' read cont_id cust_code bac bsb bid
do
    if [ "$cont_id" == "" ] || [ "$cust_code" == "" ] || [ "$bac" == "" ] || [ "$bsb" == "" ] || [ "$bid" == "" ]; then
        echo $cont_id,$cust_code,$bac,$bsb,$bid >> $SOURCE_DIR/dummyRejectedRecords.csv

    elif [ "$cont_id" == "Customer Code" ] && [ "$cust_code" == "Customer" ] && [ "$bac" == "Billing Account Code" ] && [ "$bsb" == "Bank BSB" ] &&[ "$bid" == "Bank ID" ]; then
        echo $cont_id,$cust_code,$bac,$bsb,$bid >> $SOURCE_DIR/dummyRejectedRecords.csv

    else            
        echo "Contact_Id = '"$cont_id"'"
        echo "Customer_Code = '"$cust_code"'"
        echo "Billing_Account_Code = '"$bac"'"
        echo "Bank_ID = '"$bsb"'"
        echo "Bank_BSB = '"$bid"'"
        echo ""

        #ADD YOUR PROCEDURE HERE
    fi
done < $SOURCE_DIR/dummy.csv
```

The problem is that 1st row is not being ignored
and this is being appended to 1x1 value of csv Customer Code = 'ï»¿Customer Code'

even if header is ignored the 1st value of next row is appended with ï»¿

Could someone help me here (without using awk command)
Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: ï»¿ is the stupid MS Byte Order Mark. To remove it, first run your file through `dos2unix`.

Comment: ./NIR19802.sh: line 7: dos2unix: command not found

any other alternativee of dos2unix with syntax please!!

Comment: sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < orig.txt > new.txt

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use a simple control variable to skip the first iteration, provided that the file always contains a header that has to be ignored as the first line.

Add this before the first `if` statement inside the loop:

```sh
if [ -z "$HEADER_DONE" ]; then
    HEADER_DONE=1
    continue
fi
```